# Bibliography entries with link to use in text, referencing back to the use in text

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, back-referencing, backref

I stumbled upon this citation (**See Image below**) with references to the use of the citation in the text. I.e. if one clicks on one of the red numbers the pdf reader jumps to the position where I used the cite command.

What do I have to change to get this into my bibliography?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the option `pagebackref` while loading the `hyperref` package?

Comment: These page numbers are usually called "backref"s in the TeX world. There is a `backref` package, some bibliography packages know options of that name and `hyperref` has the `pagebackref` option.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will look through backrefs and will see if I make it work :)

Comment: I answered my own question below. Thank you for the input guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This links to the use in the text is (as @Mico already mentioned) called backref.

I found two ways to achieve the desired backrefs:

1. Using the pagebackref argument when using the hyperref package i.e. `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}`. This is how it looks after compilation:

[image: compiled result using hyperref]

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%important lines defining the backref%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

%describing a bib file inside a text file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Bla bli blub \cite{A01}
\newpage
Blub bli bla \cite{B02}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}  
\bibliography{general}


\end{document}
```

2. The second way can be done by using biblatex with the backref=true argument along with the hyperref package i.e.: `\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
   \usepackage[]{hyperref}`. After my opinion, it is even a bit prettier than the first option.
   [image: an example of using biblatex for backrefs]

A minimal working example can be found below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %important lines to create the backrefs
    \usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[]{hyperref}

    \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{general.bib}
    @misc{A01,
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Alpha},
    }
    @misc{B02,
      author = {Buthor, B.},
      year = {2002},
      title = {Bravo},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}

    \addbibresource{general.bib}

    \begin{document}
    Citing the first entry: \cite{A01}
    \newpage
    Citing the second entry: \cite{B02}

    \printbibliography        

    \end{document}
```